# jQuery troubles with each() and custom function

Tags: jquery, function, each

```
    $(function(){
        $(".test").each(function(){
            test();
        });
    });

     function test(){
        $(this).css("border","1px solid red").append(" checked");
    }
```

why is this not working? what am I missing?
this is my test html:

```
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p class="test">test</p>
    <p>test</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $(this) cannot be used in that way, because you don't specify the context of the test() function:

```
$(".test").each(function(){
        test($(this));
});

function test(el){
     el.css("border","1px solid red").append(" checked");
}
```

or

```
$(".test").each(function(){
      test.call(this);
});
function test(){
   $(this).css("border","1px solid red").append(" checked");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside of your test function, `this` is not bound to the same thing you think it's bound to. Use a debugger like firebug to see what you're actually working with.

The idiomatic way to do this would be to simply include the body of test inside of the closure  (function() { ... }).

Other solutions, you can use the apply function (https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/Apply) to control what `this` refers to. In this case, it's overkill, and actually, I find that it's best to avoid it in general.

```
$(function(){
        $(".test").each(function(){
            $(this).css("border","1px solid red").append(" checked");
        });
    });
```

Comment: If we are going to just need the function once, then the anonymous function keeps all the logic in one place.

Answer (score 0):

either `test.call(this);` or `test(this);` and change the definition.